# How can i resolve the react material ui error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const drawerWidth = 240;
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
    return {
        appBar: {
            width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        },
}});



function Dashboard() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar >
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography>Dashboard 1</Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Error- Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

can anyone help resolve this

Comment: Above code looks good, might be any other component which is throwing an error. Can you share code of other components you are using currently

Comment: May we see where do you use Dashboard?

Comment: https://github.com/Mrityunjay1/glosity-material   you can check the code here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confusing the use of Material-UI versions between 4 and 5.

But you are using version [4](https://v4.mui.com/).

You should import `makeStyles` from `@material-ui/core` or `@material-ui/core/styles` not from `@material-ui/styles`.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Refer to this.
https://v4.mui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook

Comment: yes i am using version 4 i was was working well in all other components. i am facing the error in this particular component.